# Ionic 3 popover

Tags: ionic3, popover

I am trying to use ionic v3 popover. I have also implemented the same. I have a query if we have popover arrow in ionic 3 as we have in ionic v1. If yes, whats the particular html tag. We have  in ionic 1 but its not supported in ionic v3.
I didn't find that.

Comment: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/popover/PopoverController/

Comment: if you mean click to open it, just use a button?

Answer (score 5):

Please post more information or code snippet!
Ionic 1 used AngularJS so HTML is a bit different and looks like :

```html
<button ion-button icon-only (click)="presentPopover($event)">
    <ion-icon name="more"></ion-icon>
</button>
```

TS file looks like this:

```js
import { PopoverController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({})
class MyPage {
    constructor(public popoverCtrl: PopoverController) {}
    
    presentPopover(myEvent) {
        let popover = this.popoverCtrl.create(PopoverPage);
        popover.present({
            ev: myEvent
        });
    }
}
```

Source: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/popover/PopoverController/